# 500 Internal Server Error in PHP 8.1 Array with wordpress

Tags: php, arrays

Jut updated wordpress and woocommerce to the latest versions. Unfortunately im getting a 500 Internal Server somewhere in the following lines:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'attribute_img_loop', 20 );
function attribute_img_loop() {
        global $post;
        $attribute_names = array( 'pa_sertifikalar' ); // Add attribute names here and remember to add the pa_ prefix to the attribute name
        // echo '<script>alert('.$attribute_names.');</script>';

            
        foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );
            
            if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
                $terms_array = array();
            
                if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                    
                    echo '
                            <table class="combs" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>                        
                                            <td>                            
                                                <ul class="nm-variation-control ul-control-certificate">';                                                  
                                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                                        $thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                                                        $image_id = absint( get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'nm_pa_image_thumbnail_id', true ) );
                                                        $img_src = ( $image_id ) ? wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id ) : '';         
                                                        $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute_name );
                                                        $full_line = '<li><div class="lcrap"><img id="c'. $image_id .'" data-src="'. $img_src .'" alt="" class="lazyload" alt="'. $term->name .'" /></div></li>';
                                                        array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
                                                    }
                                                    // echo $taxonomy->labels->name . ' ' . implode( $terms_array, '-- ' );
                                                    echo implode( $terms_array, '');
                                                    
                                          echo '</ul>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>';                                                  
                                                    
                }
                            
            }
        }
}
```

Just added `echo '<script>alert('.$attribute_names.');</script>';`  to check the output from the `$attribute_names = array( 'pa_sertifikalar' );`
part and saw it returns a

```
function Array() {
    [native code]
}
```

**Any idea whats going on here?** Using PHP 8.1

Comment: Did you check your server/error log?

Comment: No i didnt - let me do it

Comment: Using `alert()` for server-side debugging is asking for problems. In your specific case you have an array, and if you turn on PHP warnings you'll see `Warning: Array to string conversion`, and the JavaScript you are emitting is `<script>alert(Array);</script>` which is why you are seeing that message because JS also has a thing called `Array`: https://3v4l.org/2vQm8. Instead, go for `var_dump($attribute_names);`: https://3v4l.org/bUOSg

Comment: @ChrisHaas - thx a lot did it. returns 
        `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "pa_sertifikalar"
}`

Comment: Ah, I think I see it. Try changing `echo implode( $terms_array, '');` to `echo implode('', $terms_array);`

Comment: @ChrisHaas - great sir! did the trick. what happened here - has it to do with php 8.1? Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a discussion in the comments, the fix is to change `implode( $terms_array, '')` to `implode('', $terms_array)`.

Historically the order of these parameters didn't matter, however as of PHP 7.4 passing the array first was [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php#migration74.deprecated.core.implode-reverse-parameters) and it was completely removed in PHP 8.0.